# update json object in c#

Tags: c#, json, object, edit

I have a json object something like

```
{ "name" : "sai", "age" : 22, "salary" : 25000}
```

I want to update the json object by

```
{ "name" : "sai", "age" : 23, "Gender" : "male"}
```

Then I want result something like

```
{ "name" : "sai", "age" : 23, "salary" : 25000, "Gender" : "male"}
```

I tried something like

```
foreach (var item in actualJson)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    foreach (var newItem in newJson)
    {
        if(item == newItem)  // always returns false, anything wrong with this?
        {
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!isFound)
    {
        // add to json
    }
}
```

I am not getting any Idea to solve this?

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if you create a json with all the elements again.

Comment: What if you create a json with all the elements again ?
Also no gender in first one,then how it gets updated.!

Comment: @utility please check the updated question.
I need something like above explained.
but it is not working, raised some exception can't add same property to object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can do something like this:

```
var json1 = "{ \"name\" : \"sai\", \"age\" : 22, \"salary\" : 25000}";
var json2 = "{ \"name\" : \"sai\", \"age\" : 23, \"Gender\" : \"male\"}";

var object1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
var object2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

foreach (var prop in object2.Properties())
{
    var targetProperty = object1.Property(prop.Name);

    if (targetProperty == null)
    {
        object1.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        targetProperty.Value = prop.Value;
    }
}

var result = object1.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

This will either add a property of json2 to json1 if it doesn't exist or it will update the value if it exists.